# How to typescript interface object type?

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
interface type {
   name?: number;
   ip?: number;
}
interface Data {
   hostname: string;
   date?: Date;
   key?: type;
}
const useData: Data = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  date: new Date(),
  typeA: {
     name: 'test',
     ip: 'localhost' 
  }
}
const useDataB: Data = {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  date: new Date(),
  typeB: {
     name: 'testB',
     ip: '127.0.0.1' 
  }
}
```

I want to use it in the above form, but it is impossible.
Can I use it like the example above?
If I can use it, how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good to use 'type' since it is part of the TypeScript language. Also you had a few bad types.

Try this:

```
interface IpType {
   name?: string;
   ip?: string;
}

interface Data {
   hostname: string;
   date?: Date;
   key?: IpType;
}

const useData: Data = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  date: new Date(),
  key: {
     name: 'test',
     ip: 'localhost' 
  }
}

const useDataB: Data = {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  date: new Date(),
  key: {
     name: 'testB',
     ip: '127.0.0.1' 
  }
}
```

Comment: I resolved the type change. thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. :D